# Firestore Hierarchical design - Courses , Students

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I have designed my json tree like so :

- students (collection)

  - studentId (document)

    - name
    - courses (collection)

      - courseId (document)
      - courseName
      - examDegree

for the student view i need to get all the courses that a specific student is enrolled in with their degrees , and for the teacher view i need to get all the students that are enrolled in a specific course with their degrees.

for the student view : db.collection('students').doc('studentId').

1- Is that design seems ok for this senario?

2- how to get query all the students that are registered in a specific course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This design is ok, but you're going to have some issues with queries as the structure is kinda 'deep'. [Denormalizing is normal](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) is a good read.

> i need to get all the courses that a specific student is enrolled in

Your structure is fine for this *specific* task where you know which student it is and you want to get their courses. You don't even need to query; just observe the node at students/studentId/courses and you'll have what you need.

> teacher view i need to get all the students that are enrolled in a
>   specific course

This one won't work with your structure. Well, that's not completely accurate as you could leverage a deep query but how about this

```
students
   studentId_0
      name: "Bill"
      courses:
        courseId_0: true
        courseId_1: true
   studentId_1
      name: "Ted"
      courses:
        courseId_1: true

courses_available
   courseId_0
     studentId_0: true
   courseId_1
     studentId_0: true
     studentId_1: true
```

With this structure you can get all of the courses a student is enrolled in via that students courses node, or for the teacher view, get all of the students enrolled in a specific course via the courses_available node.

In this case, Bill in course 0 and 1 and Ted is just in course 1

There are a number of other ways to structure this as well but this structure allows you to get the data without a query at all. Queries are a bit 'heavier' than just observing a node so if observing is an option, that's preferable.